# In simple terms, when is Thevenin Theorem applicable?

Tags: thevenin

I am current studying Undergrad Level Physics. I often encounter complex circuits (both DC and AC) and I was looking for simple ways to solve them. Hence I started to learn about Thevenin Theorem (on my own).

I wanted to ask where exactly is Thevenin Theorem applicable (or non applicable)?

From what I understand is that this theorem is mainly a way to reduce any part of a circuit with a battery and resistances into a non ideal battery.

Please note that the circuit elements I am interested in are Capacitors and Inductors besides Battery and Resistors.

---

Please pardon the question for being trivial as I as a Physics undergrad do not encounter such complex circuits as an EE undergrad.

Comment: It's a bit like cash in your pocket - you might not need it for a week or a month then, bingo, someone wants cash. So you learn thevenins and, when you need it you use it but, it's often optional and other theorems can be used if you know what you are doing. Or solve with a simulator.

Comment: Wikipedia defines Thevenin's theorem as: "For any linear electrical network containing only voltage sources, current sources and resistances .........................".

Comment: @Andyaka I have found it very useful till now. I intend it to learn it for self-dependence as complex circuit analysis was always a weak part of mine.

Comment: @MituRaj I do not know the meaning of "linear electrical network" here. When I searched it up, it was talking in terms of "signals" which is yet another unknown term for me.

Comment: If you are familiar with set of linear equations and familiar with Kirchhoff laws. You may notice that the equations are linear equations. With voltages or currents being variables and currents or voltages being known values.

Comment: @TonyStark, in analog electronics, a signal is a time-varying quantity such as a node voltage or branch current.

Comment: @TonyStark, in analog electronics a signal is a time varying voltage or current. In digital signal processing it might be a more abstract time-varying quantity. In image processing the variation could be based on position rather than time.

Comment: If you're a physics student studying electrical circuits, go look up phasors (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor, although there's probably a more reader-friendly version somewhere). It'll blow your mind.

Comment: @JohnDoe I have studied phasors. And it did blow my mind :).

Comment: @AJN by "linear equation" do you mean linear Differential equation or linear algebraic equation ?

Comment: I had assumed the differential equations were transformed into algebraic equations when I wrote that comment. (Using the Laplace transform). Or that steady state was being analysed using phasors and complex numbers. Differential equations as such weren't on my mind while writing that comment.

Comment: When I was in college, the professor teaching my physics course in electricity, magnetism, etc., was a physicist that had just wrapped up spending a few years studying at CERN. It was his first semester teaching, and we got to the section on capacitors and inductors just after we'd finished phasors in my EEE course. When I showed the phasor stuff to him, I could SEE the explosions going off behind his eyeballs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In linear DC circuits (circuits where all components act linearly), the Thevenin theorem always applies.
2. In non-linear DC circuits, the Thevenin equivalent is used as a step toward finding a solution, or for analyzing the effect of small variations of the input signals around an operating point. As a physics student, you'll already know about [perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory). You can think of the Thevenin model as the first order perturbation model of the circuit.
3. In linear AC circuits, the concept of resistance is expanded to the complex-valued [impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance) and we can again model circuits containing linear sources, resistors, inductors, and capacitors using Thevenin models.
4. In non-linear time-domain models, we can use Thevenin equivalents for each circuit element (source, resistor, capacitor, or inductor) at each time-point to model the evolution of the system to the next time-point. Then we re-calculate the Thevenin parameters for each element before calculating the next time step. In the simplest case, this is equivalent to [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) for solving the differential equations describing the circuit; some further elaboration is needed to achieve a stable solution.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Just to be precise, by "linear" you mean that my circuit equation can be represented in the form of a linear Differential Equation similar to the one I write with Kirchoff law.

Comment: In your point 1 can the voltage sources and values of resistances, capacitances etc be variable or they need to be constant?